# Wget/Curl execute urls doesnt work

Tags: php, cron, wget, putty

I have a site with cache. I want to cache all pages at night by a script.
If i execute the following in the browser it works but if i do this by Crontab in Putty it wont work.
Does someone has experience with this and maybe a solution?

script.php
Curl:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://url.com');
```

Crontab:

```
12 10 * * * wget http://domain.com/divers/cache/script.php
```

Solution:

```
<?php 
    system("wget -mrp domain.com/etc/etc/");
?>
```

Comment: Is your CRON actually running? It might be worth putting the full path to wget in there too.

Comment: I have tested it by a simple mailscript. So that works... But it doesnt execute the url...

Comment: Wrap the wget call in a script and execute that, you can then add additional logic/logging in the script to help you debug.

Comment: Soory i dont understand it. Do you have an example?

Comment: This works system("wget -mrp http://domain.com/etc/etc/") How can i close this post?